# How to find element and click on html with jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

I have a html page and I would like to perform click event on iframe page.

```
<h3 id="test">
<a href="#" data-id="1"> hi</a>
```

I am using jQuery:

```
var rightwareBody = $("#iframe").contents().find("body");
var rightwareElement = rightwareBody.find("a");
```

but there are multiple "a". how to differentiate that it belongs to "test"

How can I find something like find "a" under "test"?

Answer (score 0):

a under test would be

```
$("#test a")
```

Basic jQuery selectors work much like CSS selectors.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `data-id` to get the element you want instead of getting all the anchor elements. I assume data-id is unique as its name suggests.

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/q2xNA/)**

```
rightwareBody.find("a[data-id='1']");
```

If data-id is not unique then you can use #text in selector to make the selection unique.

```
rightwareBody.find("#test a[data-id='1']");
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `.data("id")` this will return `1`

[Data](http://api.jquery.com/data/)